# python write mysql messy code

Tags: python, mysql

When inserting chinese into mysql table using python，the values in mysql database are incorrectly encoded.

**Code:**

```
insert into operationlog(user_id,opt_sub,operation,hours,times) " \
"VALUES('1439712376272310', '6-25', '打开-地图-北朝上(定位按钮的状态)' ,'15', '2016-01-04 15:21:51');
```

But in the table，like this
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZjdr.png)

In python code，I used # -- coding: utf-8 -- in the first line. In mysql ,I used utf8.

Why does the 2nd value end up with the wrong encoding in the mysql table?

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3? In python 2 you need to put a 'u' in front of the string literal to make it a unicode string.

Comment: Can you post your Python Code snippet so that its more clear?